# Como fazer minha webview abrir links de outros apps

Tags: android

Tenho uma aplicação webview e quero que ela abra links de outros apps, já coloquei o intent filter agora preciso achar o código que faz ela abrir links de outros apps. Obrigado a quem responder.

Comment: Você quer que outros apps "enxerguem" e consigam enviar um link pro seu app e a partir disto o seu app possa abrir o tal link?

Comment: Sim, já consigo adicionar meu APP no filtro de intenção mas não sei como fazer minha webview obter o link enviado de outro APP, pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente você deve definir no seu `AndroidManifest.xml` o filtro:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Você precisa adicionar um tipo de scheme ao menos por `intent-filter` também para definir o tipo de url que pode receber:

```
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <data android:scheme="https" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
</intent-filter>
```

Ou criar até o seu próprio *scheme*, por exemplo `meuapp:`:

```
    <data android:scheme="meuapp" />
</intent-filter>
```

Depois dentro de `onCreate`, você deve rodar o comando `getIntent().getData()`, exemplo:

```
import android.net.Uri;

...

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final WebView minhaWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);

    final Uri urlintent = getIntent().getData();

    if (urlintent != null) {
        minhaWebView.loadUrl(urlintent.toString());
    }
}
```